# проблема с yandex mapskit для android на java

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

вот пример кода на который ругается android studio:

```
Point aa = new Point(45.004019, 41.137300);
mapView.getMap().move(new CameraPosition(aa, 11.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0), null);
```

вот собственно ошибка:

incompatible types: Point cannot be converted to LatLng
mapView.getMap().move(new CameraPosition(aa, 11.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0), null);

как быть? делал по оф. документации

Comment: Если добавить в минимальный пример ваши строка как есть, все работает. Похоже, что ошибка где-то ещё. Нужен минимальный пример, на котором это поведение можно будет повторить. Вы можете выложить его проектом на GitHub или загрузить на Яндекс Диск и указать ссылку. Если минимальный пример нужно скрыть от посторонних, пришлите его в поддержку сервиса — maps-api@support.yandex.ru